# Why does calling this function as follows not result in sendNotification being called severy 60 seconds exactly on the minute?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to execute a database query every whole minute. How can I do this accurately? 
I have an attempt at this below, but it does not work correctly. The first call is accurate, but the subsequent calls are not on the correct time.

```js
 const db_days = require('./models/dayOfWeek'); 
 const db_meds = require('./models/medicine');

async function hourlyEligibleNotifications() {
    const dayOfWeeks = [
        'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
        'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
    ]; 

    const d = new Date(); 
    const today = dayOfWeeks[d.getDay()];
    const hour =  d.getHours();
    const medicineIds = (await db_days.findById({ _id: today })).medicineIds;
    const meds_db = await Promise.all(
        medicineIds.map(medicineId => {
            return db_meds.find({ _id: medicineId , times: hour });
        })
    );
    return meds_db; 
}
function sendNotification(meds_db) {
    console.log(meds_db);
}

async function executeFuncEveryMinute(func) {
    const d = new Date(); 
    const sec = d.getSeconds(); 
    const hr = d.getHours();
    setTimeout(func, (60 - Number.parseInt(sec)) * 1000);
    setInterval(func, 60000);
}
executeFuncEveryMinute(() => {
        hourlyEligibleNotifications()
        .then((result) => sendNotification(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    });
```

?

Comment: What is the variance? How much difference are you seeing?

Comment: Like 30 to 40 seconds after the first one.

Comment: Can you drop a console.log in executeFuncEveryMinute and see if that is showing the variance too? I have a feeling this could be because of the asynchronicity of the hourlyEligibleNotifications function.

Comment: @MadhavSharma I added ```executeFuncEveryMinute(() => {
        console.log('variance');
        hourlyEligibleNotifications()
        .then((result) => sendNotification(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    });``` and it is printing out variance in the same exact time as the other output, and it is still 20 to 40 seconds off.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `executeFuncEveryMinute(func)` to the following

```js
function executeFuncEveryMinute(func) {
    const d = new Date(); 
    const sec = d.getSeconds(); 
    const hr = d.getHours();
    const msUntilNextMinute = (60 - Number.parseInt(sec)) * 1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      func();
      setInterval(func, 60000);
    }, 
    msUntilNextMinute);
}
}
```

And it works okay now.